# Xcode14 beta(iOS 16), SwiftUI, _clockHandRotationEffect doesn't exist anymore

Tags: swiftui, home-screen-widget, ios16, xcode14

in order to achieve clock animation on home screen widget. i use

```
_clockHandRotationEffect(.custom(cycleTime), in:.current, anchor: .center)
```

but on Xcode14, it doesn't exist anymore.
[image]

any replacement?

Comment: Use public rotation effects or affine transform... and don't use private API ever.

Comment: @Asperi  i need continuous, real-time updates  animations

Comment: Use TimelineView

Answer (score 5):

use Xcode13 and Swift to build a static library. Then call the methods exposed by the static library from Xcode14.

Comment: Hey how to make this work. I am unable to find out

Comment: @TechAV check this out https://github.com/everettjf/Xcode13ClockHandRotationEffectModifier